# How to read from an Azure queue in an Azure function, without a Queue Trigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

If I have an Azure Function that produces data for a queue, it's very simple: I just set it up as a parameter to the function:

`[Queue("myQueue")] ICollector<MyType> myQueue`

Is there any analogous way to read data back out of the queue?  All the information I can find on reading from queues in Azure Functions talks about Queue Triggers, which is not what I'm trying to do; I want a timer-triggered function that will batch-process elements from a queue.  How do I get a "queue reader" in my function?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or problems you're facing with your work.  A timer-based trigger is still a trigger. perhaps you're looking for more information on bindings? [function bindings timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: @BrettCaswell I know how to make a timer trigger.  What I don't know is how to pass a queue reader into it, like how I pass a queue *writer* into a function with `ICollector` and the `Queue` attribute.

Comment: Can't you create a Queue Reader Function with the prescribed function bindings, then request data from your Queue Reader Function anywhere within your main function?

Comment: @RobS. What are you saying?  What is a "queue reader function"?  Do you mean a queue-triggered function?  That's what I'm specifically trying to not do.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question. So you want to get the next batch from the queue when you request it, right?

Comment: @RobS. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Would dequeuing messages work.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-tutorial-queues?tabs=dotnet%2Cenvironment-variable-windows#dequeue-messages

Answer (score 2):

I read your question as if you need a [timer triggered fuction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp), to take messages (dequeue) of an queue.

So you need to create an timer triggred function like so:

```
[FunctionName("TimerTriggerCSharp")]
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    DequeueMessage("nyConnection");
}
```

That then calls your function to `dequeue` a message of the queue like so from the
[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues?tabs=dotnet)

```
public void DequeueMessage(string queueName)
{
    // Get the connection string from app settings
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"];

    // Instantiate a QueueClient which will be used to manipulate the queue
    QueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, queueName);

    if (queueClient.Exists())
    {
        // Get the next message
        QueueMessage[] retrievedMessage = queueClient.ReceiveMessages();

        // Process (i.e. print) the message in less than 30 seconds
        Console.WriteLine($"Dequeued message: '{retrievedMessage[0].Body}'");

        // Delete the message
        queueClient.DeleteMessage(retrievedMessage[0].MessageId, retrievedMessage[0].PopReceipt);
    }
}
```